# Navigation is not working in angular 5

Tags: angular5

After login from my login component i wanted to navigate to my home component.But it does not navigate or load the home component.Below is my login component.

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

loginForm: any;
loading = false;
error = '';
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createForm();
}

constructor(public router: Router, private authService: AuthenticationService, private fb: FormBuilder) {

}

login() {
    let credential = this.loginForm.value;
    this.authService.authenticate(credential).subscribe((res) => {
        if (res) {
            this.router.navigate(['/home']);

        } else {
            this.error = 'user or password is incorrect';
            this.loading = false;
        }
    })
}

createForm() {
    this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
        userName: null,
        password: null
    });
}
```

}

login function is used to call authenticatation service.If service return true then it navigate to home component.Authentication service returning true but it does not navigate to home component.Below i specified function which is used to authenticate user

```
authenticate(credentials): Observable<boolean> {

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
    console.log('option' + JSON.stringify(credentials));
    return this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(credentials), options)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            console.log(response.json());
            let token = response.json() && response.json().token;
            let shopId = response.json() && response.json().shopId;
            if (token) {
                window.localStorage.clear();
                window.localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ username: credentials.userName, token: token, shopId: shopId }));
                this.loggedIn.next(true);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        }).catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error));

}
```

this function return true when user is a valid user and based on that login component ought to navigate to home component.it is returning true but navigation is not working.

Comment: Do a console.log of res in the login function and see what it logs

Comment: @Chad K it prints true.

Comment: not sure if this matters, but in the Angular Routing & Navigation page, they have the router private in the constructor for a component. Try that? Also, check to see if that function will route to it based on the function itself and not a returning call. As a test, you can do login() { this.router.navigate(['/home']); }